# Why has my solid view shading gone really dark?

Tags: 3d-view

I just noticed that the shading in my solid view is really dark. I can't find how to change it back.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals of your object in edit mode?

Comment: Yes, and it's not just for one project, it's for all of them.

Comment: What render engine is used? Share this information in such questions please, it's really important when finding solution in this case

Comment: Try resetting to factory settings from the file menu. This will get rid of any changed shortcuts or any other settings you've adjusted, but it sounds like you may have changed the OpenGL lights blender uses in the viewport, and that will be the easiest way to get them back to normal.

Answer (score -4):

Go to file > Load factory settings

Comment: Note that this will reset all saved settings including enabled addons, all kinds of interface options, file paths etc. In certain cases this is the only way of course, but it's a bit overkill to just change shading in the viewport

Comment: Is there another way to reset the OpenGl lights? Manually you could get pretty close, but it's the only way I know to reset them to the exact default values.